# How to get phone in Okta claims

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, .net-6.0, openid-connect, okta

I'm using IdentityServer4/.NET 6.0 and Okta to implement SSO.

We are using Authorziation Code flow.

Here is my setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenIdConnect", options =>
        {
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true; // doesn't work
            options.SignInScheme = "idsrv.external";
            options.SignOutScheme = "idsrv.external";
            options.Authority = "https://mysaas.oktapreview.com";
            options.ClientId = "0oa1ml149rjc2sybG0h2";
            options.ClientSecret = "secretHere";
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.Scope.Add("email"); // this works
            options.Scope.Add("phone"); // this doesn't work
            options.Events = new MyOpenIdConnectEvents();
        });
}

public class MyOpenIdConnectEvents : OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    public MyOpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidatedImpl;
        OnUserInformationReceived = OnUserInformationReceivedImpl;
    }

    private Task OnTokenValidatedImpl(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        context.Success();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task OnUserInformationReceivedImpl(UserInformationReceivedContext context)
    {
        // Never gets executed
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This method is called via the `Login()` method:

```
private IActionResult ForwardToIdentityProvider(string returnUrl, string loginHint)
{
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(Callback));
    const string provider = "oidc";
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = callbackUrl,
        Items =
        {
            { "scheme", provider },
            { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
            { "loginHint", loginHint }
        }
    };

    return Challenge(props, provider);
}
```

This is where I access the claims:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("idsrv.external");
    var claims = result.Principal.Claims.ToList();
    // Code omitted for brevity
    return Ok();
}
```

The `claims` object has this (notice there is no `phone` claim):

[image]

You can see the scopes in the HTTP request URL:

[image]

I've set up the default authorization server in Okta to have a `phone` scope/claim:

[image]
[image]

I can see the phone number coming through in the token preview:

[image]

Is `phone` meant to come through via the `UserInfoEndpoint`?

If so, since I have `options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true`, why doesn't the `OnUserInformationReceivedImpl()` method get executed?

I noticed email comes through even without having set up a custom claim/scope in Okta.

How can I access the `phone` claim?

Comment: see my blog at https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/ where I go through how to debug claim problems in openidconnect.